# Is there an official hand mudras record?

Tags: training, identification

I was trying to search for a matching hand mudra where just three fingers are touching the other hand with the others apart. I learned it along with a basic ground stance of maintaining three to four points of contact with the ground. Other than that it was supposed to have an official martial arts style which used the same mudra.

I was hesitant to just show pics of it so you'll have to bear with me on any minor hand position mistakes. Also, note that there are only three fingers for contact plus my body itself for a possible fourth. It does differ from the Hakini mudra, which connects all fingers, in case there is a misunderstanding.

[image: Side Shot]
[image: Front shot]

Comment: An pictorial representation of the mudras would be useful.

Comment: There's some mention of mudras in ninjutsu, as an aid to meditation.  There's are details on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuji-in#Meanings_in_Ninjutsu), and a list of the hand positions elsewhere on the same page (yours isn't listed).  I haven't heard of any other martial art using such hand gestures: you mention there should be one using this hand gesture, do have no leads at all (e.g. is it an Indian martial art, or perhaps Chinese)?  As for an "official hand mudras record" - what makes anything official?  Google turns up lots of lists and images for hand mudras.

Comment: @user433534 I'm not sure my information is accurate since I first found it on vhs. I just used parts to help me with Judo and several boxing forms. Google seemed to have only a limited number of hand mudra types. The video itself was from the 90's and did have Michael Jackson in it either as a main part or without his permission. Searches for that were showing just numerous other unrelated videos of course. I'm not sure how significant the overall mudra was even in the video. Same as making 3-4 points of ground contact outside of its use in various positions and for general use like walking.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! If you go to the Google Play Store and simply enter 'Mudras' into the Search field, you will see, most likely, 'Mudras Apps' appear as one of the choices: that is what you want to click on.

You are, I think and hope, going to be very pleased to find *several* apps! Oh, and make sure, before you install any of the apps, to click on the green 'Read More' link for more information. With several million apps on thousands of subjects, you can easily understand the sad fact that with that many apps, they can't all be good or even exactly what you are looking for sometimes. However, you did mention that you were wanting a record or detailed list of Mudras.

I can tell you with confidence that you will be able to find at least a couple of apps with clear visual and written techniques on several different ones [Mudras], and even cross-referenced into, for example, desired effect or unblocking of a particular energy flow, or even by ailments.

I personally have installed, and used 3 different apps. Two of the 3 exceeded my expectations, and the third one was mediocre, though I was still able to glean a fair amount of information for my needs at the time. I am sorry to say I am terrible at remembering the exact names of the apps. As I said before, though: Read the finer details to ensure that the apps or apps you install meet your needs.

I am sorry to say that I am not familiar enough with Mudras to quite understand what you meant by an Official Record of any of the Mudras that I have ever seen and/or tried.

Comment: Welcome to the site. First, please check out the [help] to see how we work. Second, you can edit your post at any time and format them. Unless you are on mobil, you should see a nice preview of your post. Stack supports a slightly enhanced version of markdown. I've edited your post for now.

Comment: Could you name the apps you found good?

Comment: Sorry, but this is really nothing more than "Hey, I tried some apps and they were great, but another one wasn't, go look" which is essentially "go try google" style of answer. We at least would need some substantiation of what you are claiming.